# Перевести с PHP на python: XOR с ключём для строки

Tags: php, python

Есть код на php:

```
$newmsg = $newmsg . ($message[$i] ^ $key[$i % $kl]);
```

Как он будет выглядеть на python?
Предполагал, что так, но не получилось:

```
newmsg+=str(msg[i]) or str(key[i % kl])
```

Comment: ^ - не or, это тот же ^ в питоне.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [how to do bitwise exclusive or of two strings in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612720/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612720/how-to-do-bitwise-exclusive-or-of-two-strings-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Предполагая, что вы хотите весь цикл на Питон перевести, а не только одну итерацию, соответствующую индексу `i`, то чтобы выполнить [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2) каждого байта заданной строки с заданным ключом в Питоне 3:

```
from itertools import cycle

def xor(message, key): 
    return bytes(a^b for a, b in zip(message, cycle(key)))
```

Пример:

```
>>> key = b'key'
>>> xor(b'hello world', key)
b'\x03\x00\x15\x07\nY\x1c\n\x0b\x07\x01'
>>> xor(_, key) # и обратно
b'hello world'
```

Нужно заметить, что если вы делаете [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2) для шифрования, то ключ (`key`) должен иметь длину не меньше самого сообщения (`message`) и не использоваться более одного раза.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так должно быть:

```
newmsg += chr(ord(msg[i]) ^ ord(key[i % kl]))
```