# Кодирование текста в произвольный двоичный код и обратно. Пример: "А" <-> "01100011"

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, кодировка, byte

Мне нужно преобразовать строку, например `"А"`, в строку двоичного кода, например `"01100011"`, потом обработать немного двоичный код, пропустив его по функции "Исключающее ИЛИ" с другим двоичным кодом, например `"01100011"` с `"11000010"`, тогда выйдет `"10100001"`, и обратно перевести получившийся код в читаемую строку, например в `"Т"`.

При этом, я хочу использовать русскую, английскую и украинскую раскладку и цифры, со знаками припинания. Не подскажете, как это сделать на Python 3?

Вопрос состоит в том как в Python преобразовать строку в двоичный код и обратно используя *любой* алгоритм кодировки?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входной и выходной строк и алгоритм получения `'T'` из `"11000010"`?

Comment: Нет, алгоритм кодировки может быть любым, хоть [МТК-2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%A2%D0%9A-2) :) Мне нужны функции, которые быстро переведут текст в двоичный код, любым способом!

Comment: Т.е. вопрос состоит в том как в Python преобразовать строку в двоичный код и обратно используя __любой__ алгоритм кодировки? ;-)

Comment: Да, именно это мне и требуется)

Comment: Связанный вопрос  [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279) и [Simple Python Challenge: Fastest Bitwise XOR on Data Buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119761/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Чтобы произвольный текст превратить в "01"-строки (биты):

```
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(encoding, errors), 'big'))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))
```

И обратно:

```
def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0'
```

Пример:

```
>>> text_to_bits("мiр")))
'1101000010111100011010011101000110000000'
>>> text_from_bits(_)
мiр
```

См. [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279).

---

Чтобы выполнить XOR над двумя строками, нет необходимости биты в виде ascii-строк выражать:

```
from itertools import cycle

def xor(message, key): 
    return bytes(a^b for a, b in zip(message, cycle(key)))
```

Достаточно текст в байты закодировать, используя `.encode()` метод:

```
>>> key = b'key'
>>> xor('hello world'.encode(), key)
b'\x03\x00\x15\x07\nY\x1c\n\x0b\x07\x01'
>>> xor(_, key).decode() # и обратно
'hello world'
```

См. [Перевести с PHP на python: XOR с ключём для строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567844/23044).

Для больших строк, можно numpy использовать:

```
import numpy as np   # pip install numpy 

def slow_xor(aa, bb):
    a = np.frombuffer(aa, dtype=np.byte)
    b = np.frombuffer(bb, dtype=np.byte)
    return np.bitwise_xor(a, b).tostring()
```

Пример:

```
>>> slow_xor(b'hello...', 'миръ'.encode())
b'\xb8\xd9\xbc\xd4\xbe\xae\xff\xa4'
```

Если вы хотите ускорить эту функцию, см. [Simple Python Challenge: Fastest Bitwise XOR on Data Buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119761/4279).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Но как перевести "b'\xb8\xd9\xbc\xd4\xbe\xae\xff\xa4'" в "читаемую" строку?

Comment: @Nazar: не всякий набор байт является текстом (представьте данные картинки, пожатого архива). Если сделать XOR двух случайных фрагметов текста, закодированных в байты, используя какую-нибудь кодировку, то результат не обязан быть текстом в какой-либо ни было кодировке. Считайте XOR операцией шифрования, если `'миръ'` это ключ, то чтобы расшифровать (достать исходный текст), можно снова XOR применить: `xor(b'\xb8\xd9\xbc\xd4\xbe\xae\xff\xa4', 'миръ'.encode()).decode()` -> `'hello...'`

Comment: Я тоже так думал. Пока не попробывал сделать это! Оказалось, что для xor нужно чтобы были одинаковые длины. А у b'\xb8\xd9\xbc\xd4\xbe\xae\xff\xa4' и b'миръ' длины разные! Поэтому обратно не получается получить изначальный текст.

Comment: @Nazar: длина одинаковая: 8 байт (`len('миръ'.encode()) == 8`). `b'миръ'` это вообще SyntaxError (код для Питон 3, так как вопрос имеет метку [tag:python-3.x]). Верно, что размер для xor одинаковый нужен (поэтому `cycle(key)` и используется в одной из реализаций -- не используйте для секретов)

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже разобрался, проблема у меня была) Спасибо большое за помощь :)

Answer (score 5):

Решение поддерживающее [Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) AKA Plane Unicode символы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)):

```
s = 'отака собі тестова - String !'

def encode(s):
    return list(map(lambda x: "{0:b}".format(ord(x)).zfill(16), s))

def decode(lst):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(int(x,2)), lst))
```

Тест:

```
In [10]: lst = encode(s)

In [11]: lst
Out[11]:
['0000010000111110',
 '0000010001000010',
 '0000010000110000',
 '0000010000111010',
 '0000010000110000',
 '0000000000100000',
 '0000010001000001',
 '0000010000111110',
 '0000010000110001',
 '0000010001010110',
 '0000000000100000',
 '0000010001000010',
 '0000010000110101',
 '0000010001000001',
 '0000010001000010',
 '0000010000111110',
 '0000010000110010',
 '0000010000110000',
 '0000000000100000',
 '0000000000101101',
 '0000000000100000',
 '0000000001010011',
 '0000000001110100',
 '0000000001110010',
 '0000000001101001',
 '0000000001101110',
 '0000000001100111',
 '0000000000100000',
 '0000000000100001']

In [12]: decode(lst)
Out[12]: 'отака собі тестова - String !'
```

Comment: `join()` бы еще :)

Comment: @Alban, `join` можно добавить после того как автор пояснит что значит `"обработать немного двоичный код"`... ;-)

Comment: Я не дочитал вопрос, только заголовок :)

Comment: @MaxU, мне надо чтобы все символы двоичным кодом отображались с одинаковой длиной. И как этот двоичный код перевести обратно в читаемую строку?

Comment: @Nazar нули добавь и будет тебе одинаковая длина, но зачем это нужно?