# Как получить 8 разрядный двоичный код из каждого символа

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
def TTB():
     a = bytearray (text1, "cp1251")
     b = list(map(int, a))
     c = list(map(str, a))
     for i in range (len(c)):
          if (int(len(c)) < 8):
                c[i] = "0" + str(c[i])
     f = ' '.join (c)
     int_in = int(f, 16)
     bin_out = bin(int_in)[:2].zfill(len(f.strip())*2)
     converted = str(bin_out)
text1 = input("your text:")
c = TTB()
print(c)
```

Например символ 1 будет 49 и 1001001, а мне надо чтобы было 01001001. И ещё ! Это 33 и 110011 а надо 00110011. Как получить каждый символ из ASCII на 8 разряд 0-255

Comment: Посчитайте длину получающейся строки и добавьте нулей в начало до 8.

Comment: Второй вариант - на проверке младшего/старшего бита делать преобразование. И если вы впишете 8 сдвигов, лидирующие нули сами получатся.

Comment: Вообще-то `zfill` есть же, и вы его используете, только в другом месте. Если вам нужно добить строку `s = '1001001'` до 8 разрядов, сделайте для нее `s.zfill(8)`.

Comment: zfill(8) получается только для 1го символа. Если символ повторяется, то 0 теряются. Например 111 -> 049049049 в дв. си 1001001000001001001000001001001 всего 31, а должен получиться 32

Comment: связанный вопрос [Кодирование текста в произвольный двоичный код и обратно. Пример: "А" <-> "01100011"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715681/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
def str2bin(text: str, encoding='cp1251') -> str:
    return ' '.join(
        bin(c)[2:].rjust(8, '0') for c in text.encode(encoding)
    )


text = "Hello"
print(str2bin(text))

text = "Привет"
print(str2bin(text))
```

Консоль:

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
11001111 11110000 11101000 11100010 11100101 11110010
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку синтаксиса на join

Comment: @user270218, сейчас я посмотрю в ваши мысли и пойму как вы скопировали мой код и что за ошибка там :) UPD. Думаю, что при копипасте у вас там отступы сломались :)

Comment: Смысл в том, что я ввожу исходные данные  например: 12ратаьвл!?:'* . Выходные данные будут каждый символ имеет свою цифру по ASCII (1=49,я=255) вот беру 49=01001001, я=11111111

Comment: А на  консоле получается 1001001 7 символов (! = 33) 110011, но мне надо 00110011 если 3 раза повторяется то должен получиться 32 символов

Comment: @user270218, 7 символов не может получиться с мои кодом из-за `.rjust(8, '0')`. `print(str2bin("12ратаьвл!?:'*"))` -> `00110001 00110010 11110000 11100000 11110010 11100000 11111100 11100010 11101011 00100001 00111111 00111010 00100111 00101010`

Comment: Я такой невнимательный что забыл ] спасибо вам большое.

Comment: @user270218, бывает :D

Comment: @gil9red, кстати `.rjust(8, '0')` эквивалентно `.zfill(8)`. Не понятно, правда, зачем сделали отдельный метод для этого, может это специально оптимизированный вариант.

Comment: @user270218, в ASCII нет кириллицы.

Comment: можно сразу [весь текст в "01"-строку (биты) перегнать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715779/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Работает в Python 2.7 и выше:

```
>>> '{0:08b}'.format(1)
'00000001'
>>> '{0:08b}'.format(33)
'00100001'
```