# Дешифровка потокового кода по нескольким шифротекстам с одинаковым ключом

Tags: python, криптография

Дано несколько зашифрованных текстов, представленных в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления, для перевода использовали http://www.asciitable.com. Шифрование производилось поточным методом - брали оригинальный текст и делали xor с неизвестной последовательностью. Неизвестная последовательность для все шифротекстов одна и та же. Задача - найти эту неизвестную последовательность

Моя идея - xor (сложение по модулю два) двух шифротекстов даст xor открытых текстов, тк ключ одинаков и просто сократится. Не понимаю как использовать xor в шестнадцатеричной системе. Питон спокойно ксорит, но на выходе исключительно числа, букв нет. Для начала надо в двоичную переводить или нет?

Шифротекст 1:
848F45C9E27729EF9C844DD8BA04AA4B198EEAB1CE6AAD86C2AFDF16DE0B9C3A763B2EFB9135966E190FA6B80F1E00DCC5B5298EC65A3E0B9D32B558B235A1DD82D5FB514F35BE2FB71E822B1233F2152CBDFBEBCA2AAEA404E23D

Шифротекст 2:
91C70899D37131ED819205939005E5040E84A987DE79AD86C2AF9E17C443D165232B6BA6D025967B5052E3AA431A1DD7DCB52EC3D4053E11943AF055B961E0929487E3404325A233B51E8B364060FA1C34B1E7ED9E20AFA741FA7674F4EBCF40B10871394AAE2BF258FF63C1DFCD5370548A55AAF98B7D1F7CDA21A7BFBA350762BC1C864D264157ACF1AC43B5ED79E703704F665F49036280DF

Шифротекст 3:
8782008AC07667FF9092088C9D19EC540483A481877EB18ADFA49E10CF4E946B2E6268F2D822D37D1E09A2BB5F0452CCD3E1278ED05B71119277F750B461E8C1C486E94D5261B62FB41E8E365C33E8143FA7B5E1853BA4E011FE6468F5E78953FE15232241AE6FE244EC2AD5DFD11E70549D07FEA9BE70183BA569A7BCB767

Шифротекст 4:
848F459BC43826FE90D75C8F9A5CB85D1B8FB9D5C86FF98CDFB8CE10C84CC669366361E8913E9D6D5015ABAA5B5D13C9D9AE31DD875D761AD510FA4FA533EFDF819BF803522EF734A35BCD3B4035E91C7AB2FAFE892CE1B40EB1717FE2A68401E51066764AA42BE206BA22C9D49F1C7B5FC953BBE88B34037E8774AFA3BB664636A40BC9692C5347ACFAE140B4EB79F70933486C4A1D087E9285185D30892C7FA243490838438391F2641C23BD762B0686FACB1DE325C75DC05B2D80AD7B86A3

Шифротекст 5:
848F459BC43826FE90D75C8F9A5CB85D1B8FB9D5C86FF98CDFB8CE10C84CC669366361F29C7187601115E3BC471411CD95B62FC2CB09751A9027B54AA522F3D79086AC504727B261B64C82341239F20C28F4F9E59E3DADA541E27A7EF3A29D0DB1196D3209BF27E65EBA34CFD9DC1B354D804BBFA99471146BD672A3B2AC701231EC1D8848260544ACFBE105A3F02CF1467452694A4F0461829F095D7BC61C6EB20058474B42999AF6665928

Comment: Да, надо перевести в внутренне представление машины, что бы каждые две буквы перставляли собой байт. В языке C это был бы обычный байт, над которым можно было бы делать xor. для питона наверное лучше подойдут разложение этого текста в массив, содержащий коды символов (в внутреннем представлении). Двоичным специально не называю, что бы не вздумали получать строку, состоящую из 0 и 1

Comment: связанный вопрос [Кодирование текста в произвольный двоичный код и обратно. Пример: "А" <-> "01100011"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715681/23044)

Comment: xor двух текстов поломать проще, чем xor текста и случайного ключа. Связанный вопрос [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59/43422)

Answer (score 1):

> Не понимаю как использовать xor в шестнадцатеричной системе

```
>>> import binascii
>>> b1 = binascii.unhexlify('848F45C9E27729EF')     # hex to bytes
>>> b2 = binascii.unhexlify('91C70899D37131ED81')
>>> bytes(a^b for a, b in zip(b1, b2))  # xor cipher-texts
b'\x15HMP1\x06\x18\x02'
```

---

Как с этим работать: допустим у нас есть текст, закодированный в ascii:

```
>>> plaintext1 = b'hello world'
```

можно его зашифровать, используя случайный ключ:

```
>>> import os
>>> key = os.urandom(len(plaintext1))
>>> key
b'\xbd\xa3\xae\\\xc9\xae\x0b\x9b\xa1x\xad'
>>> xor = lambda x, y: bytes(a^b for a, b in zip(x, y))
>>> ciphertext1 = xor(plaintext1, key)
>>> ciphertext1
b'\xd5\xc6\xc20\xa6\x8e|\xf4\xd3\x14\xc9'
```

и расшифровать обратно:

```
>>> xor(ciphertext1, key)
b'hello world'
```

зная расшифрованный текст, можно найти ключ:

```
>>> xor(ciphertext1, plaintext1)
b'\xbd\xa3\xae\\\xc9\xae\x0b\x9b\xa1x\xad'
```

Зная часть текста, можно часть ключа получить (вплоть до одного бита):

```
>>> xor(ciphertext1[-5:], b'world')
b'\x0b\x9b\xa1x\xad'
```

---

Допустим, "случайно" тот же ключ использовали для другого текста:

```
>>> ciphertext2 = xor(b'supersecret', key)
```

Вопрос, как имея шифртексты, узнать ключ:

```
>>> ciphertext1.hex()
'd5c6c230a68e7cf4d314c9'
>>> ciphertext2.hex()
'ced6de39bbdd6ef8d31dd9'
```

Предположив, что исходный текст является [текстом в понимании file(1) утилиты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392391/4279), к тому же все байты в ascii диапазоне:

```
textchars = bytes({7,8,9,10,12,13,27} | set(range(0x20, 0x7f)))
```

Можно составить таблицу всех возможных xor:

```
>>> all_xors = sorted((a^b, (a,b))
...                   for a in textchars
...                   for b in textchars)
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> xor_table = {k: set(chr(a)+chr(b) for _, (a,b) in gr)
...              for k, gr in groupby(all_xors, key=lambda p: p[0])}
>>> cc = xor(ciphertext1, ciphertext2)
```

В `cc` ключ сократился, поэтому `a`, `b` это кандидаты на байты из исходных текстов (первого и второго соответственно).

Использовать `xor_table` можно так:

```
>>> i, choices = min(((i, xor_table[b]) for i, b in enumerate(cc)),
...                  key=lambda i_s: len(i_s[1]))
>>> assert (chr(plaintext1[i])+chr(plaintext2)) in choices
```

В данном случае выбор не сократился. При комбинировании более двух текстов, зашифрованным одним ключём, количество кандидатов может  сократиться. Если этого не достаточно, то можно [использовать частотную информацию](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64/43422), к примеру, `E` буква гораздо более вероятна чем `Z` в английском тексте. В обычном тексте часто должен пробел возникать, другие знаки препинания. Вот похожая задача, в которой ключ не только между текстами, но даже внутри одного текста повторно используется: [How to break XOR cipher with repeating key?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28955/1665)