# non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему эта конструкция:

```
data = bytes.fromhex(hex(int(binary_code, 2))[2:])
```

может выдавать следующую ошибку:

> ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 39

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
classmethod bytes.fromhex(string)
```

> This bytes class method returns a bytes or bytearray object, decoding
>   the given string object. The string must contain two hexadecimal
>   digits per byte, spaces are ignored.

Т.е. этот метод разбивает на байты шестнадцатеричное число, откусывая от него по две цифры на каждый байт. Если у вас метод `hex` возвратил шестнадцатеричное число с нечётным количеством цифр, то метод `bytes.fromhex` выкинет ошибку.

Comment: Как возможно избежать этого?

Comment: @Andrey, ну, добавляйте ведущий ноль, если длина нечётная

Comment: @Andrey, вообще говоря, этот метод https://stackoverflow.com/a/30375198/7485582 должен решать вашу задачу

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, вы хотите превратить "01"-строку (биты в виде ascii `'0'`/`'1'` символов записанных) в соответствующие байты:

```
>>> bits = "0101010001001111001000000100001001000101001000000100111101010010"
>>> assert len(bits) % 8 == 0
>>> n = int(bits, 2)
>>> n.to_bytes(len(bits) // 8, 'big') or '\0'
b'TO BE OR'
```

[Кодирование текста в произвольный двоичный код и обратно. Пример: "А" <-> "01100011"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715681/23044)

---

Ошибка у вас возникает, если `hex()` возвращает нечётное количество шестнадцатеричных цифр, что может быть к примеру для символов с кодами `< 16` таких как новая строка:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(hex(int(bin(b'\n'[0])[2:], 2)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

Чтобы избежать ошибки, до полного байта дополнить нулями биты можно:

```
>>> bin(b'\n'[0])[2:]
'1010'
>>> bits = _
>>> bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))
'00001010'
>>> assert len(_) % 8 == 0
```