# Из бинарного в ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня код

```
a = "a"
b = [bin(c).replace('0b', '').rjust(8,'0') for c in a.encode('cp1251')]
print(b) # ['01100001']
```

Как обратный процесс осуществить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение "в лоб":

```
chr(int('01100001', 2)) # a
```

Для списка:

```
items = ['01001000', '01100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
text = ''.join(chr(int(b, 2)) for b in items)
print(text) # Hello
```

Comment: Тут кирилл. буквы не правильно переводить

Comment: Вопрос отмечен дубликатом, предлагаю посмотреть на [ответ того вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715779/201445)